Unable to eliminate backslashes from the JSON output via Pyspark
Below is my output dataset:
{"_id":"","steps":[{"cacheHit":false,"completedAt":"2024-08-01T11:24:43.702Z","data":"{\"selfiePhotoUrl\":\"\"}","id":"selfie","inner":{"isSelfieFraudError":false},"startCount":0,"startedAt":"2024-08-01T11:24:43.698Z","status":200}]}
{"_id":"","steps":[{"cacheHit":false,"completedAt":"2024-08-01T11:03:01.296Z","data":"{\"country\":\"Botswana\",\"countryCode\":\"BW\",\"region\":\"Gaborone\",\"regionCode\":\"GA\",\"city\":\"Gaborone\",\"zip\":\"\",\"latitude\":-24.6437,\"longitude\":25.9112,\"safe\":true,\"ipRestrictionEnabled\":false,\"vpnDetectionEnabled\":false,\"platform\":\"web_mobile\"}","id":"ip-validation","startCount":0,"startedAt":"2024-08-01T11:03:01.233Z","status":200},{"cacheHit":false,"completedAt":"2024-08-01T11:22:30.609Z","data":"{\"videoUrl\":\"video/14bcc3c7-243f-4ecd-a5d2-edf7193c866e.mp4\",\"spriteUrl\":\"s\",\"selfieUrl\":{\"media\":\"66ab6ff561c966001eafb0b6\",\"isUrl\":true}}","id":"liveness","inner":{},"startCount":1,"startedAt":"2024-08-01T11:22:29.787Z","status":200}]}
{"_id":"","steps":[{"cacheHit":false,"completedAt":"2024-08-01T11:24:40.285Z","data":"{\"country\":\"Mexico\",\"countryCode\":\"MX\",\"region\":\"Mexico City\",\"regionCode\":\"CMX\",\"city\":\"Mexico City\",\"zip\":\"03020\",\"latitude\":19.4203,\"longitude\":-99.1193,\"safe\":true,\"ipRestrictionEnabled\":false,\"vpnDetectionEnabled\":false,\"platform\":\"web_mobile\"}","id":"ip-validation","startCount":0,"startedAt":"2024-08-01T11:24:40.251Z","status":200}]}
{"_id":"","steps":[{"cacheHit":false,"completedAt":"2024-07-31T20:57:55.762Z","data":"{\"videoUrl\":\"https://something.com\",\"spriteUrl\":\"sel\",\"selfieUrl\":{\"media\":\"66aaa5529e9323001dd5436d\",\"isUrl\":true}}","id":"liveness","inner":{},"startCount":1,"startedAt":"2024-07-31T20:57:54.206Z","status":200}]}
{"_id":"","steps":[]}
{"_id":"","steps":[{"cacheHit":false,"completedAt":"2024-08-08T03:32:28.183Z","data":"{\"videoUrl\":\"https://something.com\",\"spriteUrl\":\"\",\"selfieUrl\":{\"media\":\"66b43c4b338114001ebb6ec9\",\"isUrl\":true}}","id":"liveness","inner":{},"reused":false,"startCount":1,"startedAt":"2024-08-08T03:32:27.717Z","status":200},{"completedAt":"2024-08-08T03:32:35.869Z","connectedDocumentType":"national-id","data":"[{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":333,\"name\":\"UK Most Wanted\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.457Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":469,\"name\":\"EU Members of Parliament\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.457Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":472,\"name\":\"FBI Most Wanted\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.458Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":467,\"name\":\"CIA World Leaders\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.492Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":471,\"name\":\"US Marshalls Service\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.528Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":437,\"name\":\"US Bureau of Industry and Security\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.544Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":455,\"name\":\"US Denied Persons\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.544Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":480,\"name\":\"DEA Most Wanted\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.545Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":466,\"name\":\"CoE Parliamentary Assembly\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.547Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":458,\"name\":\"US OFAC\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.564Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":481,\"name\":\"Personas de Interes\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.583Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":439,\"name\":\"INTERPOL Red Notices\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.599Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":463,\"name\":\"Swiss SECO Sanctions\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.628Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":470,\"name\":\"UN Consolidated Sanctions\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.637Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":468,\"name\":\"Banco Interamericano de Desarrollo\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.638Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":430,\"name\":\"GB Consolidated List of Targets\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.651Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":328,\"name\":\"UK Bank of England Sanctions list\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.665Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":417,\"name\":\"AU Gov Dept of Foreign Trade and Affairs\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID  \",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.671Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":843,\"name\":\"EU financial sanctions\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-1963\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.679Z\"},{\"dataSource\":\"document-data\",\"country\":\"PE\",\"documentType\":\"national-id\",\"watchlist\":{\"id\":1026,\"name\":\"SAT 69B\",\"watchlistType\":\"basic\"},\"searchParams\":{\"documentNumber\":\"43265524\",\"fullName\":\"DAVID\",\"dateOfBirth\":\"17-12-2332\"},\"searchResult\":null,\"searchedAt\":\"2024-08-08T03:32:34.724Z\"}]","dataSource":"document-data","id":"watchlists","reused":false,"startCount":1,"startedAt":"2024-08-08T03:32:31.13Z","status":200}]}

Now, when I display the data, it shows proper records without any backslashes. However, when I write this data as .json files it adds slashes as can be seen in the data above.
For this, I used .option("escape","") property but it didn't work.
The schema of the steps column is a string and therefore it adds backslashes in the output but I want to remove this.
Any suggestions are appreciated

It needs the backslashes in order to be able to re-read the string into valid JSON. What problem is solved by removing those backslashes?

Okay but I need to dump this data to the warehouse and it because of these backslashes the size of the row increases due to which I am not able to load it. Even if I load it because of the nested types and all the logic on the query side will become too complex.

If you'd rather ignore the nested objects, I'd recommend deleting them in your python code before the serialization step

I can't ignore anything. I need every attribute unfortunately

From your examples, the occurrence of backslashes is approx. 2%. I don't quite see how that has such a huge impact on JSON ingest time. But if for whatever reason you still want to delete just the backslashes in a JSON-ified string, you can do it with newS = oldS.replace('\\', '')

This is the data frame column's data. Also, this record is just an example of one column. Like this, there are lots of columns with lots of nested attributes. Just imagine, one record exceeds 16MB of data.

Also, as I mentioned, these backslashes are produced while writing the data to the target and not while displaying the data so how come replace will help me I am not sure.

It'll "help" by removing them, as you asked... But by removing the It'll create invalid JSON. Sounds like you need a nested from_json call, not string manipulation
